# Multiple directories in single svn:externals property

Tags: svn

Suppose I've got svn repository A which contains a bunch of directories:
trunk/dir1
trunk/dir2
trunk/dir3
...

I want to use a subset of these directories in repository B.  One way to do this would be to set an svn:externals property that would just bring in all of A: `A https://path/to/A/trunk`.

Since I only want a subset of these directories though, I'd rather bring in just what I need.  This is fine - I can set the property to only bring in say dir1 and dir2

```
dir1 https://path/to/A/trunk/dir1
dir2 https://path/to/A/trunk/dir2
```

This does what I want, and it does seem to make my checkout quicker when A contains a ton of directories I don't want.  What I've noticed though is that when I go to do an svn update (particularly when nothing has actually been updated in A), this takes a lot longer since it has to check each directory listed in the svn:externals property to see if the revision has changed... when I just svn:externals in the whole trunk, the svn update is quicker because it just has to check one directory.

Effectively what I'm looking for is some syntax that would represent that I want multiple subdirectories but that since they're all subdirectories that svn only has to check the revision history once.  Notionally, something like this:

```
dir1,dir2 https://csdrepos/path/to/A/trunk/dir1,dir2
```

I can't find reference to any syntax like this... is there no way to do this?  Any other tips on how I might speed up my svn updates without needing to svn:externals in the kitchen sink and slow down my initial checkout?  I can't really reorganize the directory structure of A because different repos will want a different subset of A's directories.

Comment: I think the main question is: Are the different dirs of A not actually worth to be put in separate repos? That would fix your issue.

Comment: Short answer is no, I think the different dirs in A all belong in the same repository... it's analogous to if you were svn:externals'ing in something like boost - there's a ton of code in boost that's related and builds off itself, so it makes sense from boost's end that it's all together, but as an individual user you may want only a particular subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comment into account the most efficient solution seems to include the external in a 'special' folder (e.g. /ext)

Then adding symlinks to the relevant folders in /ext in the place you want.

The result is only a single 'external' download and only the relevant directories cluttering your listing in the places you want.